# Contruction: Bijective, continuous map from one topological space $X$ into itself that is not open

Tags: general-topology

Could anyone give an example for a bijective and continuous map $X \rightarrow  X$ that is not open (and thus not is a homeomorphism)? The topology on $X$ must be se same.

I suppose there must be some simple examples, but I wasn't able to find one yet.

Some things I tried and that cannot work: The topology must be infinite. Linear maps even on infinite dimensional Banach spaces cannot work (Open Mapping Theorem). Maps $\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ in the real numbers cannot work either.

Thank you for answers.

Comment: bijektiv=bijective?

Comment: In that post different topologies are conisdered on the domain and the range. OP wants the same topology. @Javi

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy How about [Are continuous self-bijections of connected spaces homeomorphisms?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20913/are-continuous-self-bijections-of-connected-spaces-homeomorphisms/20932)

Comment: @PaulFrost How about the post I'm linking to?

Comment: @YuiToCheng Yes, duplicate!

Comment: @PaulFrost Isn't your link same as teh one posted by YuiTo Cheng?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes. I voted to close the question and the comment was generated automatically. But YuiTo Cheng found it!